# Run an ajax script before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day.

I'm having a problem with running a ajax call before a form submits. I'm just a newbie web developer so please bear with me.

My code is like this:

```
$( function() {
 $('#formname' ).submit( function() {
  $.post( 'validation.php', $( this ).serialize(), function( data ) {
   if( data == 'something' ) return true;
   else return false;
  } );
 }
} );
```

This code is not working for me. Is there something wrong with the code or are there other ways to attain this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? validate before submitting?

Comment: yes sir Sandeep G B... I would like to validate the form contents with records on my database...

Comment: any feedback my friend ? my solution worked or not ?

Comment: sorry sir erimeturk, I have been busy for a while. Yeah it worked but instead of a div, I used a button instead... Thanks so much... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define click event your submit button. and then when you click it, first do your post and then submit form.

html :

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

js:

```
  $('#other').click(function() {

   $.post( 'validation.php', $('#target').serialize(), function( data ) {
     if( data == 'something' ) {
         $('#target').submit();
     }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir erimerturk... That is what I also came up just recently... Trying that right now...

Comment: What exactly do you expect by returning false in the AJAX callback?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but it's very ugly and you really don't want this.

```
$( function() {
 $('#formname' ).submit( function() {
    var returnValue;
  $.post( {
     async: false, // This makes it possible
     url: 'validation.php', 
     data: $( this ).serialize(), 
     success: function( data ) {
         if( data == 'something' ) returnValue = true;
         else returnValue = false;
     }
  } );
  return returnValue;
 }
} );
```

But why do you want this? Because you can just do another Ajax function and be ready. And after you done your ajax requests you can do a `document.location= "newlocation.html"`. Because now your application will wait untill you ajax request is done. And if your ajax request will take 10 seconds, people can't use your page for 10 seconds.

If you just always `return false` and do the Ajax request where you will handle the form. And oncomple you do the `document.location`, will be a better option. So your application will not get stuck.

Comment: Sir Niels thanks for the fast reply.. I would also try your method... But I think that I will try putting the ajax call on the submit button click and then submit the form once a valid ajax return value comes back... and I will also put a wait message while the ajax request is still processing...

Comment: No need to use Sjax for this purpose. You can easily submit the form after the async callback executed.

Comment: +1, I agree. Ajax call prior to submit is not required. Perform client side validation and submit the data. If the submitted data is not valid (you need to perform double validation as you can't trust client data) then throw back the error.

Comment: True, validation through Ajax is not required, but the question is how to return the value. Not how to solve it client side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false;` in the submit handler, not inside the AJAX callback. However, even better is changing the function to accept a parameter `e` and then calling `e.preventDefault();` even before doing the AJAX call. If the validation succeeded, use `$('#formname')[0].submit();` to actually submit the form without calling your submit handler again.

PS: Better use a plugin such as the excellent [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and the [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: Sir ThiefMaster thanks for the fast answer... I would try your suggestion and also look into the plugin...